# update nextcloud inside docker

Tags: docker, nextcloud

After accidental run, I can't get nextcloud's database and image in sync.

My database is somehow updated to the latest version, but the image (apps) are not.

In my config.php the version is: `'version' => '20.0.5.2'`

My version.php shows: `$OC_Version = array(22,1,1,2);`

If I spin up docker image version 20.0.12, the image keeps restarting with this error:

```
Can't start Nextcloud because the version of the data (22.1.1.2) is higher than the docker image version (20.0.12.1) and downgrading is not supported. Are you sure you have pulled the newest image version?
```

But If I start the latest (the same version of the "data") v22.1.1.2, I can't finish the update because:

```
Updates between multiple major versions and downgrades are unsupported. Can't start Nextcloud because the version of the datais higher than the docker image version and downgrading is not supported.
```

So I am kind of stuck! I can't run previous the version because the database reports it is updated, and I can't update to the last version, because it is not supported.

What should I do?
I read I have to update 'gradually' but the database reports it's already the latest version.

Answer (score 1):

Just in case somebody is still looking for answer, you need to change your `version.php` file back to the version matching your last working configuration (in this case probably to `20.0.5.2`). Definitely use backup of this file if you have it.

If you have no backup, you can make it yourself as described here: https://help.nextcloud.com/t/skipped-major-version-21-23-did-not-run-the-updater-yet/139638/2?u=vset